# Como pegar um número solto no meu HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, regex

Considerem o seguinte código:

```
<span class="test"><span style="color:green">Teste</span>:</span> Text<br><br>
<span class="test"><span style="color:green">Mais</span>:</span> Text<br><br>
<span class="test"><span style="color:green">Número</span>:</span> 250<br><br>
```

Como eu faço para separar aquele número (250) que vem logo após a palavra "Número" para ser tratado posteriormente em Javascript? Acho que é possível com expressões regulares, mas não consegui fazer o efeito...

Os `span` podem se repetir infinitamente, e preciso procurar pelo número que vem logo após.

Comment: Você pode alterar o html? O "correto" seria colocar os números dentro de spans próprios. Aí você pega fácil, sem regex.

Comment: Infelizmente neste caso não tenho essa possibilidade... Teria que pegar o valor como esta no exemplo...

Comment: O problema não está muito claro, mas se a única coisa que você quer é o número, é bem fácil, basta "[0-9]+".

Comment: Agora que vi que você diz "preciso procurar pela palavra e o número que vem logo após...". Que palavra exatamente você quer além do número?

Comment: Infelizmente outros valores podem não ser strings ali também.. Por exemplo, posso ter ou não um campo escrito data e logo em seguida um outro valor numérico entende? Teria que ser apenas o número que vem logo após a palavra "Número".. Não sei como faria isso..

Comment: Você pode fazer o match de toda a string "Número</span>:</span> ([0-9]+)" com a parte do número entre parênteses para criar um grupo, e depois pedir somente o grupo com "\1"

Comment: Você poderia postar uma resposta com um exemplo amigo? Não sou experiente com Regex.. A propósito, tenho muita dificuldade com o mesmo! Ficaria grato, se puder fazer isso!!

Comment: Wagner, eu sei fazer no R. Eu teria que ver como é implementado o regex no JavaScript. Não deve ser complicado (aqui tem algumas dicas http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html),  mas somente depois posso dar uma olhada. Quem quiser responder antes pode ficar a vontade, abs!

Comment: "Acho que é possível com expressões regulares" Acho que não custa repetir... Expressões regulares não são a melhor ferramenta pra tratar de HTML (ou XML). Se puder evitar, evite-as. Apenas em alguns casos *muito* limitados elas são aplicáveis, e ainda assim há chance de - se o HTML mudar no futuro - a solução que antes funcionava começar a apresentar problemas. Uma solução como [a do bfavaretto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13582/215) é a ideal, não apenas por ser "mais rápida pra processar", mas principalmente por ser mais correta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode atravessar o DOM em vez de usar regex, é [bem mais rápido](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-dom) para processar. Faça o seguinte:

1. Ache os `<span>` que contêm `"Número"` e, para cada um:
2. Acesse o nó pai dele (`parentNode`) e pegue o nó ao lado (`nextSibling`)
3. Converta o valor para número e guarde em algum lugar.

O código abaixo faz isso:

```
var rotulos = document.querySelectorAll('.test span'), rotulo;
var valores = [], valor, node;
for(var i=0; i<rotulos.length; i++) {
    rotulo = rotulos[i].textContent || rotulos[i].innerText;
    if(rotulo === 'Número') {
        node = rotulos[i].parentNode.nextSibling;
        valor = node.textContent || node.innerText;
        valores.push(Number(valor));
    }
}
// valores agora contém os números
```

<sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PNn8M/)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Olá,
Considerando que o código dos spans fica diretamente dentro do body, ficaria assim:

```
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
var regex = /<\/span> ([0-9]+)/g;
var resultados;
//Itera por todas as correspondências do número
while(resultados = regex.exec(html)){
    console.log(resultados[1]);
}
```

O método exec retorna um array com a correspondência(match) além dos grupos capturados pela sintaxe entre parênteses (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). Na sexta linha pegamos o primeiro grupo, que corresponde ao número, no índice 1.